# curl not working in php script and crontab but does through browser

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have a php script that runs a curl command and retrieves data. afterwards I update the database with the data. This works fine for me when I execute the script directly but not when using crontab. My crontab line is:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php http://mydomain.com/script.php
```

When I use this through crontab I see the database updated but not the content received from the curl function. 
As well, If I try to run the php script from ssh it works fine as well.

Comment: Does the script reside on a remote machine? If not, why not just do: `/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php` ?

Comment: I tried doing so firstly... It did not work so I tried changing it to the full url.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I managed to work it out just now by adding

> ## !/usr/bin/php

to the top of the php script. Im not exactly sure why did that fix the issue but now it is working.

Comment: Because with that line you're somewhtat telling which language the script is in. If there's no such declaration, it usually defaults to bash, and bash wouldn't be able to run a php script.

Comment: But the php is indeed working. Only the part of cURL is not working within the script.